# Android NDK: Problems including headers

Tags: android-ndk

When I try to compile my app I see...

```
/bin/sh: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
```

But in my Android.mk I have...

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := iconv-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := extlib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libiconv.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := extlib/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_MODULE    := git
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DNO_GETTEXT -DSHA1_HEADER=<openssl/sha.h>
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,, \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.c))
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog -ldl
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := iconv-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And the ls of the extlib/include/openssl directory is...

```
aes.h       conf.h      e_os2.h     krb5_asn.h  opensslconf.h   rc2.h       ssl3.h      x509_vfy.h
asn1.h      conf_api.h  ebcdic.h    kssl.h      opensslv.h  rc4.h       stack.h     x509v3.h
asn1_mac.h  crypto.h    ec.h        lhash.h     ossl_typ.h  ripemd.h    symhacks.h
asn1t.h     des.h       ecdh.h      md4.h       pem.h       rsa.h       tls1.h
bio.h       des_old.h   ecdsa.h     md5.h       pem2.h      safestack.h ts.h
blowfish.h  dh.h        engine.h    modes.h     pkcs12.h    sha.h       txt_db.h
bn.h        dsa.h       err.h       obj_mac.h   pkcs7.h     ssl.h       ui.h
buffer.h    dso.h       evp.h       objects.h   pqueue.h    ssl2.h      ui_compat.h
comp.h      dtls1.h     hmac.h      ocsp.h      rand.h      ssl23.h     x509.h
```

So as you can see the header file is there and should be fine to include. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? I am guessing it is an issue in my Android.mk

Comment: "openssl/sha.h" seems to work but on another project it uses .//Rope/b2Rope.h:#include <Box2D/Common/b2Math.h> and this works fine with the C_INCLUDES. This may be more of a C question

Comment: I thought something worked but I was wrong

Comment: define PROJECT_ROOT_ANDROID_INC:= path to header file as well in the .mk file